# Close tab when focus on cross icon of tab in ChromeTabs Library WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create close tab when user click on cross icon.I were search out many alternative before few days.But i do not find exact answere.

```
  <ct:ChromeTabControl   Background="#FF76828D"    Foreground="Black"   BorderThickness="2"  x:Name="chromeTabeControl"  Margin="224,31,-5,88"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
                             AddTabCommand="{Binding AddTabCommand}"
                           CanMoveTabs="False"   CloseTabCommand="{Binding  CloseTabCommand}"  SelectedTabBrush="#FF909BA4" BorderBrush="#FF6A6262" AddTabButtonBrush="#FF8D3030" OpacityMask="Black" LayoutUpdated="chromeTabeControl_LayoutUpdated"    >
            <ct:ChromeTabItem     Name="dashboard_tab" Margin="0,0,0,0"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Header="Dashboard"    >
            </ct:ChromeTabItem>
</ct:ChromeTabControl>
```

By doing this I can remove tab.But I dont know how we can implement this action on cross image icon.

```
            chromeTabeControl.Items.Remove (dashboard_tab );

Any one help me.He would be appricated for me.Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the GotFocus event on windowform.Then I have create back an event to close ChromeTab that I were created. This code close the current tab that is open.
Go to XAML file create window event like this.

```
 XAML:
    GotFocus="Window_GotFocus"

Code Behind :
 private void Window_GotFocus ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
            {
            if ( e.OriginalSource.ToString ( ) ="System.Windows.Controls.Button") {
                chromeTabeControl.Items.Remove ( chromeTabeControl.SelectedItem );
                }

            }
```